# JasperReports runs perfectly in Netbeans and my PDF is generated but the compiled .jar does not

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, netbeans-7

I am using JasperReport. It runs perfectly when in Netbeans, and my PDF is generated on JRviewer.

However, when I try to run the compiled .jar file the whole JasperReports part does not work at all.(JRviewer did not appear)

I'am using jasperReport4.5.0 
Libraries in my Classpath: Commons-beanutils, Commons collections, commons digester, commons javaflow, commons logging, iText, com-jaspersoft-ireport-jasperserver , com-jaspersoft-ireport-components, com-jaspersoft-ireport, com-jaspersoft-jrx.

Could you give me some advice on this? 
thanks a lot.

Comment: do you have the stacktrace? What is the Exception?

Comment: Exception occurred during event dispatching:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(J
RClassLoader.java:157)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRCl.....        for information i am not using Spring framework and i am developping a SWING application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have not put the spring-core jar in your classpath. Maybe you are not using spring but Jasper Reports does need spring in the classpath as you may see in [Jasper Reports POM](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/4.7.0). The complete listing of artifacts required is in there.

Comment: You better check also the version of your Jasper Reports and add the other dependencies as well.

Comment: Thanks Mael for help, it works for me. I thought that spring does nothing to do with my problem but it works.